# How do I dynamically set the working directory at runtime by passing an env variable?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Here's what my Dockerfile looks like for an image I'm creating.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
ENV U_PATH="a"
WORKDIR $U_PATH
```

I override the env variable `U_PATH` when I call it using `docker run -it -e U_PATH=/mnt temp:v1 /bin/sh` but the `WORKDIR` is set during build time and I cannot change that during runtime.

Is there any way to dynamically set the working directory at runtime by passing an env variable?

Comment: Not without a custom entrypoint script.  Why would you want to, though?  I usually consider filesystem paths part of a container's external interface, and it's reasonable enough to specify that external data storage always is mounted on `/data` or some other straightforward path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not an environment variable, don't forget you can alter the working directory of a Pod's container via the [`workingDir:` PodSpec field](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#container-v1-core)

```
containers:
- name: foo
  image: 'temp:v1'
  workingDir: /mnt
```